# Package allEffects - plotting 3 charts together

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the package allEffects to create some plots for my models but I would like to have the 3 graphs it gives me in one window, in 3 different windows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`allEffects` returns a list of plots, you can plot the list elements separately, e.g.

```r
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt + disp, data = mtcars)
library(effects)
ee <- allEffects(m)
plot(ee[["hp"]])
dev.new()  ## or whatever
plot(ee[["wt"]])
dev.new() 
plot(ee[["disp"]])
```